# Name of textfield for tinymce in WYSIWYG drupal plugin

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, tinymce, wysiwyg

So I am trying to get it so that when I press a button, it inserts umlaut characters into a text area. It's written in javascript and it totally works on any text field I give it EXCEPT the tinymce editor I've given to my body edit box. I know for a fact that the id of the text area is "edit-body-und-0-value." This works if I disable wysiwyg and just have the normal text field as is. However, when I enable tinymce editor with wysiwyg, and I press the umlaut buttons, nothing gets inserted into the tinymce editor. Do you guys know how I could solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE once set-up is way more than a `textarea` (it is built in an `iframe`) and therefore it cannot be accessed the same way.

To do what you're trying to do in TinyMCE, you'd need to write a plug-in (see there : http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin), or fortunately for you a built-in TinyMCE button already exists to insert special characters, it is called "charmap" and is easy to add to your buttons list.

Comment: You sir, are amazing. I don't know how I ever missed that. You just saved me countless hours! Thanks so much.